# SSL Certificate in Lien

Tags: ssl, httpclient

Im using The Npm Package Named Lien For My web server, I Have My Certificate Located As Follows in The Image. But I Always Get an Error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
```

This is how Lien handles SSL

```
if (options.ssl) {
            options.ssl._key = options.ssl._key || fs.readFileSync(options.ssl.key);
            options.ssl._cert = options.ssl._cert || fs.readFileSync(options.ssl.cert);
            _this3.server = https.createServer({
                key: options.ssl._key,
                cert: options.ssl._cert
            }, _this3.app);
        } else {
            _this3.server = http.createServer(_this3.app);
        }
```

and This is how I Have Defined Lien

```
 let server = new Lien({
            host: "localhost"
            , port: 5000,
             ssl: {
                cer: path.join(__dirname + '/' + 'certificate.cer'),
                key: path.join(__dirname + '/' +'privatekey.txt')
            }
        });
```

path: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJLiF.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a typo -- it should be `cert` instead of `cer`:

```
let server = new Lien({
   host: "localhost"
 , port: 5000
 , ssl: {
      // v---- This has to be `cert`
      cert: path.join(__dirname + '/' + 'certificate.cer'),
      key: path.join(__dirname + '/' +'privatekey.txt')
   }
});
```